# How to remove sites from Google AdManager but keep in Adsense

Tags: adsense, tagging, google-ad-manager, gdprconsentform

I was trying to setup the mandatory GDPR thing for some ad units. While applying to sites in Adsense I get the message:

> This site is managed in Ad Manager. Go to Ad Manager to make changes.

I don't remember when/how I added those to AdManager. Checking AdManager I can apply the GDPR to those sites but seems it doesn't support all the ads formats from Adsense (like In-Feed for example).

Two questions:

- how to remove a site from AdManager but keeping it in Adsense? In Inventory>Sites I can delete but a notice says I will be removed from Adsense too which is NOT what I want
- how to use in AdManager In-Feed and In-Article?
- can Adsense and AdManager be used together?

Thanks

Comment: I am also having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet and deadline is approaching... 
I noticed they introduced a way which should delete the site (when you assign sites to a policy there is a small icon) but clicking an confirming doesn't work. 
There is also a link to "Manage Inventory" but links to 404 page...
So disappointed by Google!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ad manager and Adsense together, In-feed and In-Article Ad formats are not available in GAM.

Comment: that's the issue, I want to use In-feed and In-Article Ad too

Comment: You can setup GDPR in any of the platforms and it can work for all ad units.
So if you want to use In feed and In article Ad formats, you can use it from Adsense. On websites, you can run Adsense and ad manager ads at the same time.